# pass string as a variable in json key value pair

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to pass the value of the dummy into the id but the syntax is not proper.

```
String dummy = getSysCodeOfAccount(X_Table, "delivery");
String jsonRollups = [{"id":dummy},{"percentage":"100.000000"}];
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Second statement is not json. It expect the String array.

Comment: @Masud. You are correct. Second parameter should be json or object of arrays, right? So I can use Json.stringify?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct json string:

```
String dummy="sample";
String jsonRollups = "{\"id\":\""+dummy+"\",\"percentage\":\"100.000000\"}";
```